# How to add pop up image animation on screen

Tags: ios, ios7, core-graphics, core-animation

I'm going to make a quiz game where user will have to pick correct answer from 4 options.Those options will be image format.I want those rectangular images will appear on screen on by one by Pop Up animation.
Can you please tell me how can i add a popup animation on iPhone App? 
NB: The pop up animation should be like Pop Up transition in Keynote.I mean after Pop Up it will vibrate a little bit back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947799/ios-animation-effects-image-pop-in)

You can tinker with the values depending on how you want your animation.

Comment: Can you please tell me if i want the pop up image to be shake after pop up just like a Pop Up transition in keynote?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. But you can check cocoacontols.com for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Set default frame for all 4 images.
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    //set frame for first image
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
   //this block will call after first animation is done.so after that animate 2nd image . do same for all 4 image.
}];
```

maybe this will help you.